# Find changes made in PGSQL table using SQL in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Is it possible to create an SQL query to compare a field within a single table to see if a change has been made and if possible list the before and after?

I have the following SQL query written in Excel 2010 VBA, which connects to an Oracle PostGreSQL database

```vb
Dim au As String

au = "SELECT id, priority, flag, code " _
    & "FROM hist WHERE ( aud_dt >= '18/05/2020' AND aud_dt <='18/05/2020' ) " _

Set rs = conn.Execute(au)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With
```

Where fields include:

- "priority" is the field that I'd like to check for changes which will
  be a single number between 0-9
- "code" is the record that has been
  assigned the priority and is a mixture of numbers and letters up to 7
  characters
- "flag" shows a 1 as the active record, and 2 as an edited
  record
- "id" refers to the user account

I'd ideally like to end up with something like: `id | priority | flag | priority_old | flag_old | code`

Which should show the before and after changes to the priority. If the record shows `priority=3 and flag=2 and code=Ab12`, there must also be record with a 1 flag, as that is now the active record. If it has the same priority number for the code I'm not interested in it as that just means something else was changed instead as I have not listed all the column fields.

If the active record now shows `priority=4, flag=1 and code=Ab12`, that would be exactly the record I need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a self-join query (possibly you need to adjust date filter in `WHERE` depending on *when* items change):

```sql
SELECT h1.id, h1.priority, h1.flag, 
       h2.priority AS priority_old, h2.flag AS flag_old, h1.code
FROM hist h1
LEFT JOIN hist h2 
  ON h1.code = h2.code
  AND h1.priority <> h2.priority
  AND h1.flag = 1
  AND h2.flag <> 1
WHERE (aud_dt >= '2020-05-18' AND aud_dt <='2020-05-18')
```